# Regexp that matches user-agents of end-user browsers but NOT crawlers with >90 % accuracy

Tags: regex, browser, user-agent

I'm trying to construct a regexp that will evaluate to true for `User-Agent`:s of "browsers navigated by humans", but false for bots. Needless to say the matching will not be exact, but if it gets things right in say 90 % of cases that is more than good enough.

My approach so far is to target the `User-Agent` string of the the five major desktop browsers (MSIE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera). Specifically I want the regexp **NOT** to match if the user-agent is a bot (Googlebot, msnbot, etc.).

Currently I'm using the following regexp which appears to achieve the desired precision:

```
^(Mozilla.*(Gecko|KHTML|MSIE|Presto|Trident)|Opera).*$
```

I've observed small number of false negatives which are mostly mobile browsers. The exceptions all match:

```
(BlackBerry|HTC|LG|MOT|Nokia|NOKIAN|PLAYSTATION|PSP|SAMSUNG|SonyEricsson)
```

My question is: **Given the desired accuracy level, how would you improve the regexp? Can you think of any major false positives or false negatives to the given regexp?**

Please note that the question is specifically about regexp-based `User-Agent` matching. There are a bunch of other approaches to solving this problem, but those are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: What of bots that identify as browsers?

Comment: Macha: Obviously they will be classified as browsers. But as long as these are rare they won't be a problem given the stated accuracy goal.

Comment: Yep, errybody running a bot through your website is honest.  Best solution is to rethink what you're doing here and how you're going about it.  Most people prefer to spot bots by behavior (lots of different pages in a very short timespan) rather than user agent.

Comment: Will: See the last paragraph of the question. It is very clear on the scope of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many crawlers don’t send an Accept-Language header, while AFAIK all browsers do. You could combine this information with your regex to get more accurate results.

Comment: The only one I've seen that disobeys this is slurp:  [Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Yahoo! Slurp; http://help.yahoo.com/help/us/ysearch/slurp)] [en-us,en;q=0.5] and also if you are serving media then I think sometimes browser plugins make a request without Accept-Language if in IE (so that's a non-bot, but doesn't send Accept-Language).  Also google translate doesn't send an Accept-Language, but in general this method seems to work well.

Comment: So, as far as the logic: are you thinking `if (regex_matches || has_header) { is_human }` or are you thinking `if (regex_matches && has_header) { is_human }` will be better

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer `AND`, not `OR`. Still not absolutely reliable, but that’s not possible anyway.

Answer (score 23):

You could construct a blacklist by checking which user agents access robots.txt.

Comment: Interesting concept! Way to think outside the box.

Comment: Awesome idea! wanted to give you props & up vote for that as well :).

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather using the opposite, having a pattern for bots is much simpler

personally I use the following regex

```
/bot\b|index|spider|crawl|wget|slurp|Mediapartners-Google/i
```

Comment: That's dangerous. I've got this filtered out `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0.1; en-us; Bottle of Smoke Build/HRI66) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
`, and I only ran this on a subset of user agents we ever see.

Comment: `/bot\b|...` :-) Not sure about 'index' though, as some plugins do some weird things to user agent strings (especially in IE, pushing the length out)

Comment: you should add "curl" to your regex

Comment: This will probably also match on `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; CUBOT KING KONG) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.96 Mobile Safari/537.36` which is an Android phone